# Existence of Ring homomorphism from Formal Power series ring to a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism, formal-power-series

Let $R$ be a ring, and $S$ be a subring of $R$.
Denote $S[[x]]$ for a ring of formal power series with coefficients in $S$.
Let $\alpha \in R$ be a unit, such that $\alpha \notin S$.
Can there exist a ring homomorphism $\phi :S[[x]]->R$ such that $\phi $ sends $x\in S[[x]]$ to $\alpha \in R$?

If this question is hard to answer in general, could you answer for specific case?

For example, let R be Complex Numbers, S be integers, and $\alpha =6/5$.

EDIT: My question is restricting topology to the 'usual topology.'

Comment: Sure there can, if you have no (in particular topological) restrictions. I find it harder to come up with an example where such a homomorphism cannot exist.

Comment: i think only $f(x)=f(\alpha)$ with all $f\in S[[x]]$ can be a ring homomorphism $f:S[[x]]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ sends $x∈S[[x]]$ to $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. But consider $f(x)=\sum_{i\ge 0}{\frac{5}{6}x}^i\in S[[x]] $, it is a contradiction there

Comment: @VN_nmd: There is no contradiction (what is supposed to contradict what?).

Comment: @ Torsten Schoeneberg: Can you explain further please? For example, when $\alpha =3/4$ and R is Rationals, S is Integers, then there does not exists such homomorphism. If we take $P(x)=\sum \binom{2n}{n}x^n $ then $(P(x))^2(1-4x)=1$ and say $\phi (P(x))=g$ but $g^2$ cannot equal to $-1/2$.

Comment: The statement does not involve any topology so I have no idea what your edit is supposed to mean.

Comment: @phyam: OK, certainly there are many cases where such a homomorphism does not exist. (I see another big class of examples, namely, when $p(\alpha)=0$ for some polynomial $p(x) \in S[x]$ whose constant term is in $S^\times$; e.g., $S$ is a field and $\alpha$ algebraic over $S$.) But I found it relatively harder to come up with those than to see reuns' example for your original question, maybe because I'm used to $p$-adic numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About your example, we have an homomorphism $$\Bbb{Z}[[X]]\to \Bbb{Z}_2, \qquad \sum_n c_n X^n\to \sum_n c_n (6/5)^n$$
And $\Bbb{Q}_2$ is a field of characteristic $0$ with cardinality less than $\Bbb{C}$, by the axiom of choice it is isomorphic to a subfield of $\Bbb{C}$, thus  obtaining your homomorphism $$\Bbb{Z}[[X]]\to \Bbb{Q}_2\to \Bbb{C},\qquad X\to 6/5$$

Comment: That's what I had in my mind; maybe it's noteworthy that the same idea works for $3$ instead of $2$.

Comment: I am sorry, I quite don't understand your answer well. Do you mean that you define your homomorphism $\phi $ such that $\phi $ sends formal power series $\sum a_nx^n$ to $\sum a_n(6/5)^n$? Then if $a_n=n$, doesn't the sum equal to infinity, hence not a homomorphism?

Comment: @phyam Do you know the $p$-adic numbers $\Bbb{Q}_p$ ? It is the completion of $\Bbb{Q}$ for the absolute value $|p^n a|_p=p^{-n}$ for $p\nmid a$. The subring $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is the set of limits of sequence of integers that ends being constant $\bmod p^n$ for all $n$. Then $u_k=\sum_{n\le k} n (6/5)^n$ is a Cauchy sequence for $|.|_2$.

Comment: @reuns Thanks for reply, and I am sorry for my lack of knowledge. Are you using a metric that is different from the 'usual' one? Could you also give an example using 'usual' metric?

Comment: As you noticed there is no homomorphism $\Bbb{Z}[[X]]\to \Bbb{C}$ continuous for the two natural topologies. The only natural maps sending $X$ to $6/5$ are $\Bbb{Z}[[X]]\to \Bbb{Z}_2$ and $\Bbb{Z}[[X]]\to \Bbb{Z}_3$, then we need to compose with unnatural maps $ \Bbb{Z}_p\to\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: @reuns Hm.. I don't think I noticed that. How would you prove it?—your first sentence.

Comment: I get that when $\alpha =0$ then there exists such homomorphism, and when $\alpha $ is a unit in Z, then there cannot exist such homomorphism in the sense of 'usual metric.'